# What format is this datetime?

Tags: python, datetime, strftime

I believe this to be some kind of format produced by a Java date library of some sort.
I'm trying to parse it using Python and I'm uncertain if this could be accomplished with `datetime`. If this is not possible I'll trim the string and keep the first part for the conversion. But maybe someone knows the format:

```
25-SEP-2019 11:26:23 AMERICA/LOS_ANGELES
```

I think something like:

```
'%v %H:%M:%S %V'
 or
'%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S %Z'
```

But definitely I don't know how to parse the `AMERICA/LOS_ANGELES` bit.

Edit: Removed the expression 'java date' because people don't seem to understand is a figurative speech.

Comment: Looks like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones
Maybe try pytz: http://pytz.sourceforge.net/

Comment: FYI, there is no such thing as a "Java date".

Comment: As [Solvalou commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59151462/what-format-is-this-datetime#comment104528025_59151462), the last part is a proper time zone name in `Continent/Region` format. Never use the 2-4 pseudo-zones you see in the media such as `PST`, `IST`, `CST`. They are not true time zones, are not standardized, and are not even unique. The case is wrong on that zone name, however. Should be `America/Los_Angeles` rather than all-caps. That particular zone is used by much, though not all, of the western coast of North America.

Comment: There is nothing Java specific about your date time string, and as a Java programmer for 20 years I haven’t seen the format before. It may or may not have been produced by a Java program.

Comment: Thank you @OleV.V. that's what I needed to know. I believe it has to do with some Oracle products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing Java specific about your date time string. As a Java programmer for 20 years I haven’t seen the format before. It may or may not have been produced by a Java program.

I’m sorry, I can’t tell you how to handle it in Python (I could tell you how to produce and how to parse it in Java, but that’s not what you asked).

Comment: Thanks, i needed someone that knew more of Java to confirm my suspicion. @solvalou and Basil Bourque are on point too. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

First, you need to split your datetime from timezone, then parse it via appropriate format.

```
inp = "25-SEP-2019 11:26:23 AMERICA/LOS_ANGELES"
date_str = re.split(r'\s(?=[A-Z]+)', inp)[0].title()
date = datetime.strptime(date_str, "%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what my question is asking not to do... Plus, you are not even parsing the timezone.

Answer (score -1):

In python3, there is no Directive for any timezone like `AMERICA/LOS_ANGELES`.
For checking the local time of particular timezone.

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

tz = pytz.timezone('AMERICA/LOS_ANGELES')
la_date = datetime.now(tz).strftime('%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S')
# it will print the LA time:  `02-Dec-2019 22:49:38`
```

Its better if u can strip and split the string.

```
date_str = '25-SEP-2019 11:26:23 AMERICA/LOS_ANGELES '
date_time_timezone = date_str.strip().split() 
# ['25-SEP-2019', '11:26:23', 'AMERICA/LOS_ANGELES']
```

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what my question is asking not to do... Also, not parsing  the timezone.